# php URL variable doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, html, variables, url, get

I modified the detectmobilebrowsers.com php script to write 1 or 0 in the url passed in the redirect so I can just script which style sheet I need based on if the viewing browser is mobile or not. It's working great adding `?det=0` for not mobile or `?det=1` if it is a mobile browser. However, in my header file, my IF statement is always returning the not-mobile html regardless of the value of `det` in the  url. I'm sure this is elementary, but I can't get it!

the url format i'm using is www.cypressbotanicals.com/main.php?det=1

Excerpted from the < head > section of header.php:

```
<?php
$mob = $_GET['$det'];
if($mob==1): ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><!--is mobile-->
<?php else: ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php endif ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scheck.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Try `$_GET['det'];`  (remove the `$` from the array key name)

Comment: that was, pf course, precisely it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you're running your `$_GET`, you're looking for something that's prefixed with a `$`, which is used for PHP variables, but not this!

`$mob = $_GET['$det'];`

Will look for `https://example.com/index.php?$det=foo`

`$mob = $_GET['det'];`

Will look for `https://example.com/index.php?det=foo`

Comment: Thank you! i knew it had to be something because the second half of the if statement was executing.